# How to get query string in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, request, symfony4, php-7.2

I am trying to access the query string parameters in Symfony 4

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class Home extends Controller {

    private $request;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $request){

        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getQueryString(){

       $req = $this->request->getCurrentRequest();

       print_r($req); // see all the request data

       // $req -> grab the query parameters
       // return query parameters
    }
}
```

I am using `RequestStack` and able to see a bunch of request data when I print the result of `getCurrentRequest()` (including the query parameters I need), but most of the methods are `private` and I am not able to access them.

How does one go about getting the request URL components (including query parameters) in Symfony?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **GET** query:

```
$this->request->getCurrentRequest()->query->get('name_query');
```

For **POST** query:

```
$this->request->getCurrentRequest()->request->get('name_query');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// retrieves $_GET and $_POST variables respectively
$request->query->get('id');
$request->request->get('category', 'default category');
```

Source https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object

Answer (score 2):

This works with Symfony 6:

**GET**

```
$value = $request->query->get('name_query');
```

**POST**

```
$value = $request->request->get('name_query');
```

**BODY** (REST API returns JSON response inside body)

```
$value = $request->getContent();
```

**HEADER**

```
$value = $request->headers->get('X-header-name');
```