# query parameters null in get response

Tags: symfony

I'm developing an API with Symfony 6.4

I'm trying to do something as simple as collecting the query params that I send in a get request. But I receive null value in all the ways I'm trying to collect the 'page' data.

```
GET request: http://my-project.dev/posts/list?page=2

Controller:
#[Route(path: '/posts/list', name: 'list', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function list(Request $request): Response
    {
        $page = $request->get('page');
        $page = $request->query->get('page');
        $page = $request->attributes->get('page');
```

I'm out of ideas. Something I'm not seeing correctly? Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get query string in Symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324929/how-to-get-query-string-in-symfony-4)

Comment: No @DarkBee. I'm trying to collect the value of the query param the way it should be done and it returns null. That's why I'm asking if I've left something out or if there's something else I need to take into account

Comment: Then you will need to provide more details/research in order to pinpoint the actual issue.